# Got EOFError during loading doc2vec model

Tags: python-2.7, pickle, gensim, doc2vec

I could not load a doc2vec model on my computer and I got the following error. But, when I load that model on other computers, I can use that model.Therefore, I know the model was built correctly.

what should I do.

This is the code:

```
# coding: utf-8
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec
import gensim.models.doc2vec
from gensim.models.doc2vec import LabeledSentence
import os
import pickle
pth='/home/fatemeh/Step2/input-output/model/iterator'
model= Doc2Vec.load(pth+'/my_model.doc2vec')
```

This is the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CreateAnnoyIndex.py", line 16, in <module>
    model= Doc2Vec.load(pth+'/my_model.doc2vec')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gensim-0.13.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 1762, in load
    model = super(Word2Vec, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gensim-0.13.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/gensim/utils.py", line 248, in load
    obj = unpickle(fname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gensim-0.13.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/gensim/utils.py", line 912, in unpickle
    return _pickle.loads(f.read())
EOFError
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your model causes the problem. Are you check with same model? I mean build in a same way. please see [this page](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/860)